# how to use hcmap highchart R shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm trying to implement a hcmap like this example:

```
https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/218
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "hcmap"
```

I tried to find documentation about hcmap to understand if I'm missing some sort of package but I couldn't find it.

Hope someone could help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a new version with a new function `hcmap`. Try installing from github:

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
```

Then

```
   library(highcharter)
   hcmap("custom/south-america")
```

yields this:
[image]